# Rolle's theorem proof

Tags: real-analysis

I am having little bit of troubles in my proof. Suppose that $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $f(a) = f(b)$.

If the extremum happens over the boundary points. Necessarily f is constant function. I can't justify this. I can complete the argument otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessarily a constant function. For example, consider. $f(x) = x^2$ on [$-2,2$]. Then $f$($-2$) = $f$($2$) = $4$.  Rolles theorem says there exists a max or a minima between [$-2,2$], it doesn't say that $f$ is a constant function.

*However*: if both the maxima (M) and the minima (m) of a function on [$a,b$] are equal, then $f$ is a constant function. For example, if $M = m = 2$, then we are saying that the lowest value of the $f$ on the region and the highest value of the $f$ on the region is $2$. Clearly, $f $ has to be $2$, because or it would either have a point above or below $2$ on the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are *two* extrema guaranteed for a continuous function on a compact interval: A global minimum and a global maximum. What does it mean if *both* extrema are at the boundary?

Comment: Let us say that maximum M occurs at a. That is, we have f(a) = f(b)= M. Is it true that f is constant ? If so why is it true ? Can you Explain ?